# Include reactive text in a R markdown shiny documents

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown

I am a little lost and am unable to add a reactive test (te) in the shiny output of an R markdown document. A minimal example based on an R studio example is paste below.

Many thanks in advance!
Jean-Pierre

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderText({te})

renderPlot({
startTime <- Sys.time()
  # additional code goes here
endTime <- Sys.time() +1
te <- reactive(startTime - endTime)
hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `te <<- reactive(startTime - endTime)` to define `te` outside the `renderPlot`, use `renderText({te()})` instead of `renderText({te})` because it is a reactive expression, and finally put `renderText({te()})` to the end after it's definition.

Comment: That is wonderful! I have wasted so much time trying to figure out how this works. You've saved my day!